# How to add X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block HTML

Tags: javascript, html, security, meta

I don't know how to add this part of code into my code.
should it be in the header part?

```
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8; X-Content-Type-Options=nosniff" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>TestWebsite</title>
</head>
```

The problem is I have to add it into my code, because I did a security scan and I got that the X-XSS Protection is missing.

Comment: How you add HTTP response headers will depend on your HTTP server. You can't do it from the HTML document that is used for the HTTP response body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. This cannot be added on a HTML page.
2. It has to be added to your server page as a response.

E.g. You can add any of the following options, according to your needs.

**PHP**

```
header("X-XSS-Protection: 0");
```

**.htaccess**

```
Header set x-xss-protection "1; mode=block"
```

**Apache configuration files:**

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-XSS-Protection: "1; mode=block"
</IfModule>
```